# Some characters with diacritics are thicker than the other letters (Raleway - Google Fonts)

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a site in Czech language, that uses the Raleway font from Google Docs with latin and cyrillic subsets and still some of the characters with diacritics are thicker than the other letters. 
Here's an example. The letter `ž` is thicker than the other letters

[image: example]

In HEAD `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700,900&subse‌​t=latin,cyrillic-ext,cyrillic,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

In CSS `body{font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; font-weight: 400;}`

I'm sure I must be missing something, because when I type the word in Typecast it seems perfectly fine. See for yourself (if anything it might be thinner)

[image]

Comment: Don't use raleway font. 'o' and '0' are quite similar: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway?preview.text=0o&preview.text_type=custom

Comment: See [this article](http://untitledgam.es/2017/01/height-blending-shader/) and search for `If the heightmap factor is set to 0, both levels will become 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That character doesn't exist in that font. It's probably using the sans-serif fallback for that character.

If you go to https://www.google.com/fonts, search for "raleway" and then type that character into the "preview text", it brings up a greyed out "X". Ironically "Raleway Dots" font **does** have that character.

So, you need to find another font that supports Czech language.

[image]

Comment: Well that's just weird... I downloaded Raleway from fontsquirrel.com then used their Webfont generator and included the Czech subset and everything is fine. Except now instead of using `font-weight` I use `font-family` to use the proper fontface..

Comment: @CreamWhippedAirplane That is peculiar. Perhaps Google has an old version of that font. What you can do then is use Google fonts, and then use your font squirrel downloaded font as a fallback and see if that works? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22196906/2117156) for how to best set that up. In that answer I've done exactly that with "Ubuntu"

Comment: that's nice, but what is the reason to still use the hosted version since you already have the font stored localy? Just so that when the site is connected to the internet it will rather request from google than you to save you some load?

Comment: Caching. Website requests are cached. People use Google's jQuery CDN because if the browser has viewed another website then that request has been cached and therefore the load speed is increased significantly. Of course the downside is that it's not 100% reliable so they offset this with a fallback to a local jQuery version if the CDN can't be found. The same applies here, but maybe to a lesser degree.

Comment: Aight, thank you for the explanation, resources and help :)