# Adding google font references to ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net, google-font-api

I need to add google opensource fonts to my ASP.Net application.
Currently I've included them using the link to google apis as follows

```
<head runat="server">

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,200,300,700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>

</head>
```

But the problem is when I run my web application in the development environment without internet these fonts won't work.

So what I need to do is include these fonts as references in my ASP.Net application  just as we include javascript(.js) & css(.css) files to the application.

eg:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css"/>
<script src="jq/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So I need to run my web application without internet by adding references to google font files. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can download the google fonts and install it in your dev environment, and keep the link tags as it is, so when internet is available (in a different environment), they will be downloaded

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994372/local-fallback-for-google-web-fonts for some good suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You can download the fonts and host them on your local devel webwserver, and include them much the same way, see the google-webfonts-helper here:

https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts

This will require you to just swap out the css parts between debug and release builds, using build events or some custom processing.

edit: much more usefull info here: [How to host google web fonts on my own server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966740/how-to-host-google-web-fonts-on-my-own-server)